# Not sure why my collapsible navigation bar is not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

Hi i used bootstrap in my website, to make a collapsible navigation bar. When i resize my screen, the navigation bar collapses. However when i click on the collapsible button, the navigation bar does not appear below.

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
             <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="45" width="45">
         </a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#dogs">Dogs</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#cats">Cats</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
    </nav>
```

I have also included the bootstrap cdn links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
             <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="Logo" height="45" width="45">
         </a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsibleNavbar">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#dogs">Dogs</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#cats">Cats</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
    </nav>
```

data-toggle is supposed to be the Id of the element that you want to toggle.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- change `navbar-expand-sm` to `navbar-expand-lg`
- `data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"` attribute must match with `id="collapsibleNavbar"` so chnage id to `id="navbarTogglerDemo02"`

below is the full code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"> //change lg
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
             <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="45" width="45">
         </a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02"> //match target attribut
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#dogs">Dogs</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#cats">Cats</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
    </nav>
```